# How to read custom product attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I've added a custom attribute to a product of mine with code _ek_test_, a text field where I save a number like 0.18.

Now in my plugin I try to access that custom field however I never get something returned. I tried various methods that I found by Googling but nothing works. If I use a predefined attribute it works fine.

Here's my code

```
// returns 'ek_test';
$product_costs_attribute = $this->_config['product_costs_attribute']; 


// Load product, $item is a order item
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

// queries attribute but is nil
$bp = floatval($product->getData($product_costs_attribute));

Mage::log('Attribute value: ' . $bp, null, 'plugin.log');
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `$this->_config['product_costs_attribute']` is it ek_test? If so then you could get the value of this attribute like this:

```
$product->getData('ek_test');
```

or like this:

```
$product->getEkTest();
```

If the attribute is not set then it will be null, perhaps you want to have a default value for this attribute?

To give you an idea try doing this to see all the attributes you have in your product object:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

var_dump($product->getData());
```

Then you can get the value of any of this attributes in different ways:

```
$product->getData('attribute_name');
```

or

```
$product->getAttributeName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I just did a var_dump and can't see it there. I've now created 2 attributes and see them in the prices and general tab of the product. Why do they not show up in the var_dump? Any ideas?

Comment: In magneto admin go to Catalog->Mange Products there search for your product and check if the new attributes you created have a value, if the attributes are empty then that is the reason why you can't see the values on the var_dump.

Comment: I've filled them out with values. also I did a product attribute reindex, still no luck though.